# How Determine the number of repeated integers and their counts?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to write a program to determine the number of repeated integers in an array and their counts but the program outputs roughly fulse, so my question is what the problem in my code i do not want use any class , thanks.

for example :

Input:
Enter array size: 11
Enter array elements:
13
34
22
4
499
4
22
18
4
1
1
Output:
There are 3 repeated numbers:
22: 2 times
4: 3 times
1: 2 times

but my output is :

1:2 times 
4:3 times 
4:2 times 
22:2 times

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class repeated_elements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        // User Choose The Array Size
        System.out.println("Enter Array Size: ");
        int size = input.nextInt();

        // The Array
        int[]Array = new int[size];

        // Read The Array Elements From The User
        System.out.println("Enter Array Elements:");
        for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
            Array[i]=input.nextInt();
        }

        // Sorting The Array (Ascending Order)
        for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){

            int mini = Array[j];
            int mini_index = j;

            for(int i = j; i<size; i++){
                if(Array[i] < mini){
                    mini = Array[i];
                    mini_index = i; 
                }
            }
            int tmp = Array[j];
            Array[j] = Array[mini_index];
            Array[mini_index] = tmp;
        }

        // Count The Repeated Numbers
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

            int key = Array[i];
            int counter = 0;

            for(int j=i; j<size; j++){
                if(key == Array[j]){
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            if(counter > 1 ){
                System.out.println(Array[i]+":"+counter+" times ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your input,what is expected output and what do you get?

Comment: Instead of send it to an array you could create a hashtable and set the integer as the key then the value as the count so as you take in the input you test for the key, if it exists add one to the value but if it doesn't exist add the key with a value of one then just get the count of the keys. It may be a bit more dependable and then you're not limited by having to know the length ahead of time.

Comment: You have to account for ints beeing already counted.

Comment: my input : (13 , 34 , 22 , 4 , 499 , 4  , 22 , 18 , 4 , 1  ,1)
my output :
1:2 times 
4:3 times 
4:2 times 
22:2 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this piece of code :

```
   // Count The Repeated Numbers
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

        int key = Array[i];
        int counter = 0;

        for(int j=i; j<size; j++){
            if(key == Array[j]){
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if(counter > 1 ){
            System.out.println(Array[i]+":"+counter+" times ");
        }
    }
```

try this:

```
   // Count The Repeated Numbers
    for(int i=0; i<size; ){   //<--- note the removal of i++

        int key = Array[i];
        int counter = 0;

        for(int j=i; j<size; j++){
            if(key == Array[j]){
                counter++;
            }else{
                i=j;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(counter > 1 ){
            System.out.println(key+":"+counter+" times ");
        }
    }
```

the problem is you don't sync your `i` and `j` variable

so for an input like :

```
1 1 1 1
```

you will get

```
1:4
1:3
1:2
```

After the correction I tested the program and for input:

```
11
13 34 22 4 499 4 22 18 4 1 1
```

I get :

```
1:2 times 
4:3 times 
22:2 times
```

EDIT:
AS @CabelB suggested. it'll worth while have a look at `Map` implementation as well.

Comment: the output :
 4:2 times 
18:2 times

Comment: @amr oops my bad, I added instead of j , I put j+1, I've eddited the answer now

Comment: Why not use a Hashtable instead to save on complexity and calls? Then you can keep track of unique keys and counts in one place.

Comment: @CalebB well personally I would have used HashMap for this but the problem is array related. so I tried to answer the question that is being asked

Comment: That is true and completely up to you and the op but sense the input is derived within this method and not passed from another source it may be worthwhile to recommend other options now instead of later. Just a thought.

Comment: @amr the problem is instead of checking the next integer you check the next element of your array. that else part, is basically say, that the next element you should look is the element j which points to the next integer . also keyword break; ensure 1- you don't have to check all the elements so it makes it more efficient 2- you don't ignore  break the consistency of i and j

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would solve this with Map and counting there, but your code corrected:

public class Rep {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = {1,1,2,2,2,0};
    // User Choose The Array Size
    System.out.println("Enter Array Size: ");
    int size = input.length;

    // The Array
    int[]Array = new int[size];

    // Read The Array Elements From The User
    System.out.println("Enter Array Elements:");
    for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
        Array[i]=input[i];
    }

    // Sorting The Array (Ascending Order)
    for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){

        int mini = Array[j];
        int mini_index = j;

        for(int i = j; i<size; i++){
            if(Array[i] < mini){
                mini = Array[i];
                mini_index = i; 
            }
        }
        int tmp = Array[j];
        Array[j] = Array[mini_index];
        Array[mini_index] = tmp;
    }

    // Count The Repeated Numbers
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

        int key = Array[i];
        int counter = 0;

        for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
            if(key == Array[j]){
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if(counter > 0 ){
            System.out.println(Array[i]+":"+counter+" times ");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why not use a Hashtable instead to save on complexity and calls? Then you can keep track of unique keys and counts in one place.

Comment: i am a beginner in java and in programming at all , so in the beginning i use only (decision statements & loops & arrays)

Comment: No problem, but you will implement a HashMap in the end. It has Key-Value pairs what is very cool. You can ask later how many '1' are there.. You can create a class with two array fields (keyArray and valueArray, and keep them in synchron. Implement a Search, Put methods. Thats it. You will learn from it. ;)

Comment: @ Laszlo Lugosi ok i will look for  HashMap , and i will learn it  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok, but for one small problem. When you are outputting the number of appearances, you are going through the entire array every time, regardless if the value currently being checked was already checked before. In short, for an input array of [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], the output is 1:4 times, 1:3 times and 1:2 times and so on.

I think you need to separate the distinct values from the sorted array or at least make sure that you do not repeat the counting for values that have already been counted.

Answer (score 0):

You parse each time the whole array, so you have to skip already parsed items.
Increment the `i` counter in last for by `counter` value:

```
if(counter > 1 ){
    System.out.println(Array[i]+":"+counter+" times ");
    i +=counter;
}
```

That should be enough, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When we take a key for finding the ocurrence, first we need to check whether it is already searched for occurence (eg.4). So i have kept the key in array without any duplicates and then start searching it. It can be easily done with collections methods..

```
public class RepeatedElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // User Choose The Array Size
        System.out.println("Enter Array Size: ");
        int size = input.nextInt();

        // The Array
        int[] Array = new int[size];

        // Read The Array Elements From The User
        System.out.println("Enter Array Elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        // Sorting The Array (Ascending Order)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

            int mini = Array[j];
            int mini_index = j;

            for (int i = j; i < size; i++) {
                if (Array[i] < mini) {
                    mini = Array[i];
                    mini_index = i;
                }
            }
            int tmp = Array[j];
            Array[j] = Array[mini_index];
            Array[mini_index] = tmp;
        }
//      System.out.println("sorted array:"+Arrays.asList(Array));
        int key[] = new int[Array.length];
        int keylen = 0;
        // Count The Repeated Numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {


            int found = 0;
            int k;
            for ( k=0;k<keylen;k++){
                if (key[k]==Array[i]){
                    found=1;
                }
            }
//      11  System.out.println("k value"+k+"i value"+i);
            if (found==1)
                continue;//already counted
            else
                key[keylen]=Array[i];

            int counter = 0;

            for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
                if (key[keylen] == Array[j]) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            keylen++;
            if (counter > 1) {
                System.out.println(Array[i] + ":" + counter + " times ");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The output is attached in the screenshot.[image]